# Exit out of for loop after first event listener click executes

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working on a tic tac toe board and I would like the user to be able to click on one of the nine boxes on the board. I implemented a `for loop` to run over each div, allowing each one to be clicked by the user.

After they select their box, the computer will then make its move.

How can I stop the loop, once the user selects their box ? Thank you in advance

```js
//initial variables
let box = document.querySelectorAll(".box");
let letter = document.querySelector('.letter');
let turn = 0;
//START GAME
let userXorO = function() { //function to determine whose x and o

  let X = 1;
  let O = 2;
  
  let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) + 1; //randomizes between x and o
  
      if (random == X) { 
        return 'X'
      }

      if (random == O) {
        return 'O'
      }
    
    return random; //returns random number to function
  }

//PLAYER ONE INITIAL TURN
function turn_one() {


  for (let i = 0; i < box.length; i++) {
    if (turn === 0) {
      box[i].addEventListener("click", function(e) {
        box[i].textContent = userXorO(); //draws first user X or O 
        turn ++;
      });
      
    }
  }
}

turn_one();
```

```css
.game-board {
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #34495e;
  color: #fff;
  border: 6px solid #2c3e50;
  border-radius: 10px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template: repeat(3, 1fr) / repeat(3, 1fr);
}

.box {
  border: 6px solid #2c3e50;
  border-radius: 2px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 4em;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.player_one {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="game-board">
  <div id="1" class="box"><span id="1" class="letter"></span></div>
  <div id="2" class="box"><span id="2" class="letter"></span></div>
  <div class="box"><span id="3" class="letter"></span></div>
  <div class="box"><span id="" class="letter"></span></div>
  <div class="box"><span id="" class="letter"></span></div>
  <div class="box"><span id="" class="letter"></span></div>
  <div class="box"><span id="" class="letter"></span></div>
  <div class="box"><span id="" class="letter"></span></div>
  <div class="box"><span id="" class="letter"></span></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than adding lots of listeners that you might try to remove after the human selects a box the first time, you might find the logic easier to follow if you added only *one* listener, to the entire container (this is called *event delegation*), and check to see if the click is currently valid using a variable like `isHumanTurn`. (Of course, if the computer takes its turn *instantly*, there's no need for a `isHumanTurn` check.)

Also note that duplicate IDs in the same document is **invalid HTML** - best to remove those. (To check the index of a clicked `div` in its container, you can use `indexOf` on an array of the `div`s)

Another issue is you should construct the random `X` or `O` *once*, at the beginning of the game, not on every click, else it won't be consistent.

For example:

```js
const humanTile = ['X', 'O'][Math.floor(Math.random() * 2)];

let isHumanTurn = true;
function handleClick({ target }) {
  if (!target.matches('.box')) return;
  if (!isHumanTurn) return console.log('It is not your turn!');
  target.textContent = humanTile; //draws first user X or O
  isHumanTurn = false;
  console.log('insert function call for computer to take its turn...');
}
document.querySelector('.game-board').addEventListener('click', handleClick);
```

```css
.game-board {
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #34495e;
  color: #fff;
  border: 6px solid #2c3e50;
  border-radius: 10px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template: repeat(3, 1fr) / repeat(3, 1fr);
}

.box {
  border: 6px solid #2c3e50;
  border-radius: 2px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 4em;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.player_one {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="game-board">
  <div class="box"><span class="letter"></span></div>
  <div class="box"><span class="letter"></span></div>
  <div class="box"><span class="letter"></span></div>
  <div class="box"><span class="letter"></span></div>
  <div class="box"><span class="letter"></span></div>
  <div class="box"><span class="letter"></span></div>
  <div class="box"><span class="letter"></span></div>
  <div class="box"><span class="letter"></span></div>
  <div class="box"><span class="letter"></span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great answer ! Learned alot, thank you for taking the time and explaining everything you did. Much appreciated

Comment: Would love to know why you set the handleClick function to an object ({Target})

Comment: That destructures the argument and extracts only its `target` property. It's the same as `handleClick(event) { const { target } = event;`, except without the intermediate variable `event`.

Comment: Okay , Thank you again for the explanation !